# How can i access another script function if the script to access is not attached to the same gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour {

     public GameObject player;
     public Camera mainCamera;
     public Camera firstCam;
     public Camera camera;
     private List<GameObject> TeleportBooths;

     private TeleportationsCore tc;

     private void Start()
     {
         InstantiateObjects gos = GetComponent<InstantiateObjects>();

         TeleportBooths = new List<GameObject>();
         TeleportBooths = gos.PrefabsList();
         firstCam.enabled = false;
         mainCamera.enabled = false;
         camera.enabled = true;

         for (int i = 0; i < TeleportBooths.Count; i++)
         {
             TeleportBooths[i].AddComponent<TeleportationsCore>();
         }
         tc = GetComponent<TeleportationsCore>();
         WorkingBooth();
     }

     private void WorkingBooth()
     {
         player.transform.position = TeleportBooths[tc.WorkingBooth()].transform.position;
         camera.transform.position = new Vector3(TeleportBooths[tc.WorkingBooth()].transform.position.x - 10, TeleportBooths[tc.WorkingBooth()].transform.position.y + 10, TeleportBooths[tc.WorkingBooth()].transform.position.z);
         camera.transform.LookAt(TeleportBooths[tc.WorkingBooth()].transform);
     }

     private void Update()
     {
         WorkingBooth();
     }
 }
```

I'm doing:

```
tc = GetComponent<TeleportationsCore>();
```

But tc is null.

And the script i want to access to:

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class TeleportationsCore : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public float spinSpeed = 2.0f;

     private bool rotate = false;
     private bool exited = false;
     private int boothIndex = 0;

     private void Start()
     {
         WorkingBooth();
     }

     void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
     {
         if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
         {
             Debug.Log("Player entered the hole");
             rotate = true;
         }
     }

     private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
     {
         if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
         {
             Debug.Log("Player exited the hole");
             rotate = false;
             exited = true;
         }
     }

     void Rotate()
     {
         if (rotate)
         {
             if (spinSpeed == 350)
             {
                 rotate = false;
                 exited = true;
                 boothIndex++;
                 WorkingBooth();
             }
             else
             {
                 transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, spinSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                 spinSpeed += 1f;
             }

         }
         if (rotate == false && exited == true)
         {
             transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, spinSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
             if (spinSpeed > 0.0f)
                 spinSpeed -= 1f;
         }
     }

     public int WorkingBooth()
     {
         return boothIndex;
     }

     private void Update()
     {
         Rotate();
     }
 }
```

What i want is after i attach the script to all gameobject to get access the function WorkingBooth on TeleportationsCore.

And i don't want to attach the TeleportationsCore to the GameObject Teleport is attached on. So what other ways i have to access the WorkingBooth on TeleportationsCore ? Making the WorkingBooth public static ?

Comment: `GetComponent` gets the component object attached to the referenced `GameObject`. Calling it like that means you're trying to get it from _that_ `GameObject`. But I don't see anywhere in your script where you add a `TeleportationsCore` component to _that_ `GameObject`, just all the stuff within `TeleportBooths`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < TeleportBooths.Count; i++) {
     TeleportBooths[i].AddComponent<TeleportationsCore>();
 }
```

to:

```
TeleportationsCore[] tCores = TeleportBooths.Select(booth => booth.AddComponent<TeleportationsCore>());
```

Now just pick the core you want from the list.

Answer (score 1):

Attach the TeleportationsCore script to empty game object. To get its reference, use this:

```
TeleportationsCore core = FindObjectOfType<TeleportationsCore>();
```

Use it for example in the Start function, as it is a bit slow.
You can find more in [documentation.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html)

Comment: **OP** wants to attach his script to all other `GameObjects`. `FindObjectOfType` only returns the first one.

Comment: @Smartis nop. OP wants to attach the Teleport script to all objects and call TeleportationsCore from there. And they don't want to have the TeleportationsCore on any object, that has Teleport.

Comment: First, you are assigning teleportationsCore to only the last Teleportations Core you add. Change it to array. Than you can use FindObjectsOfType, which returns array. [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html)